# Salesforce - how to send an ecrypted pdf to an external user

Tags: pdf, salesforce

I have several PDF file stored in Salesforce, I need to send each PDF to each different external users (external users that don't have Salesforce access) in a secure way.
I see two ways:

1. Encrypt the PDF and send it encrypted to the user mail address, then send the password by SMS.
2. Allow the external users to access the PDF stored in Salesforce using a user-password but without having a Salesforce user.
   Is there any solution for one of the two ways?
   Thanks,
   Jaime

Comment: Consider posting on dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com too, it's not very programming-related

Answer (score 0):

Content Documents (the actual table name for what you see as Files / Chatter Files / Notes) might have an option for #2. The old school Documents and Attachments - unlikely.

You can password protect the links and / or make them expire after certain date. Read up https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_delivery_create.htm&type=5

Here's ERD: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_content.htm

Alternative could be the "sign" apps on AppExchange. Check Adobe Sign, Docusign (or whatever is the name). But I suspect they're just think integrations and docs are hosted in different cloud, your organisation might have security issues with that.